# Time and Space Complexity of top k frequent elements in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

There is a small confusion regarding the time and space complexity for the given problem:

Given an array of size **N** , return a list of top **K** frequent elements.

Based on the most popular solution:

1. Use a HashMap of size **K** with the count of each entry as value.
2. Build a MaxHeap of size **K** by traversing the HashMap generated above.
3. Pop the elements in the MaxHeap into a list and return the list.

K being the number of unique elements in the input.

The space and time complexity is: O(K) and O(K*log(K)

Now the confusion starts here. We know we are dealing with worst case complexity in the above analysis. So the worst value K can take is N, when all the elements in array are unique.

**Hence K <= N. Thereby O(K) be represented as O(N) ??**

Thereby, shouldn't the space and time complexity be O(N) and O(N*log(N)) for the above problem?

I know this is a technicality, but its been bothering me for a while. Please advise.

Comment: You cannot use a hash map of size K, you need one of size N. The complexity of the solution is O(N*log(K)), not O(K*log(K)).

Comment: You're using **K** to mean two different things. First is the input to the algorithm: *"return a list of top K frequent elements"*. Second is a property of the array: *"K being the number of unique elements"*. Those two K's are not the same. The second K could be much larger than the first.

Comment: A better algorithm for the second part is QuickSelect. It's expected O(N) time and with a clever implementation will require only expected constant additional space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right since `K<N`, the time complexity for the hashmap part should be `O(N)`.

But heap only have K elements in it and has the time complexity of `O(Klog(K))` which if considered asymptotically is far larger than linear complexity of `O(N)` and hence results in final time complexity of `O(Klog(K))`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!